# Simple singleton pattern - Visual C++ assertion failure

Tags: visual-c++, singleton, c++-cli, assert

I'm recently programming a very simple logger class in Visual C++ 2010, but I have a problem. Everytime I run the program, a debug assertion failure appears.

```
Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)
```

This is how my class looks like (basically it's only a little modified from an answer here [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)):

```
class Logger
{
public:
    // Returns static instance of Logger.
    static Logger& getInstance()
    {
        static Logger logger; // This is where the assertion raises.
        return logger;
    }

    void logError(std::string errorText);

    // Destructor.
    ~Logger();

private:
    std::ofstream logFileStream;

    // The constructor is private to prevent class instantiating.
    Logger();
    // The copy constructor and '=' operator need to be disabled.
    Logger(Logger const&) { };
    Logger& operator=(Logger other) { };
};
```

And the constructor is:

```
Logger::Logger()
    : logFileStream(Globals::logFileName, std::ios_base::trunc)
{
    // (Tries to open the file specified in Globals for (re)writing.)
}
```

I found out that I can solve it by using static variables or methods somehow, but I don't understand what's wrong with this code. Does anyone know, where the problem is?

**EDIT:** FYI, the failure raises when this code is called (for the first time):

```
Logger::getInstance().logError("hello");
```

**EDIT 2:** This is the definition of `logFileName` in `Globals`:

```
static const std::string logFileName = "errorLog.log";
```

Comment: Does `getInstance()` execute properly?  Do you get to `logError()`?

Comment: Right when the instantiation should happen in the static method - I have added a comment to the code.

Comment: The assertion seems to happen in the constructor. That's the code you're not showing...

Comment: @BoPersson: The ctor is right there towards the end.

Comment: how is `Globals::logFileName` initialized?  Does it have a proper value when the logger is instantiated?

Comment: @Attila I have appended the definition at the end of my question.

Comment: That seems all right (as long as it is initialized before the Logger constructor) -- is the `getInstance()` called from a static block by any chance (e.g. when calculating the value of a static variable?)

Comment: I've compiled your code and it runs without a problem. Do you use DLLs or link several modules in your project? Could you also provide a stack trace to the assertion point.

Comment: There are some dependencies between the global variables (e.g. logger singleton and the `std::string logFileName`. Are you sure they are instantiated in the right order? (Remember, if each lives in different compilation unit, the order of construction is not defined in C++.)

Comment: I have just inspected the content of all variables in Globals namespace and I see that none of the strings has any value! It might be a problem similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467919/static-const-string-wont-get-initialized I will have a look at it and post an answer if successful.

Comment: So, the empty string wasn't the problem (however, it would be problem later). The wierd assertion failure still appears.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're calling `getInstance()` from the constructor of another global variable, and encountering the infamous initialisation order fiasco - it's unspecified whether or not `Globals::logFileName` has been initialised before any globals in other translation units.

One fix is to use an old-school C string, which will be statically initialised before any global constructor is called:

```
static const char * logFileName = "errorLog.log";
```

Another possibility is to access it via a function:

```
static std::string logFileName() {return "errorLog.log";}
```

My favoured solution would be to remove the global instance altogether, and pass a reference to whatever needs it; but some might find that rather tedious, especially if you already have a large amount of code that uses the global.

Comment: It's called from a constructor, but the constructor's object is created at the beginning of the main() function, so it's not global. Thanks for the tip, but it haven't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

C++/CLI is not standard C++ and plays by slightly different rules. Are you using C++/CLI managed code at all? (/clr compiler option?) This looks like a common problem when mixing C++ (unmanaged) code with C++/CLI (managed) code. It has to do with the way managed and unmanaged construction and destruction happens at program initialization and program exit. Removing the destructor works for me - can you do that in your Logger class?

For more details and possible workarounds:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442784/Best-gotchas-of-Cplusplus-CLI

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa0e9340-619a-4b07-a86b-894358d415f6/crtisvalidheappointer-fails-on-globally-created-object-within-a-static-llibrary?forum=vcgeneral

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?534537-Memory-leaks-when-mixing-managed-amp-native-code&p=2105565