# global static const string won't get initialized

Tags: c++

Running c++ on Ubuntu.

in configuration.h file i have this (global):

```
static const string APP_CONFIG_FILE_NAME = "cfg";
```

in my configuration.cpp (which is singleton by the way, so load configuration is called by constructor of Configuration) i do this:

```
void Configuration::loadConfiguration() {
    cout<< "config file name "  << APP_CONFIG_FILE_NAME.data();
        load();
}
```

The load configuration will be called from another global: (this is the key point for the failure)

```
Timer t(Configuration::Instance()->timeout);
```

i see that the cost string is not initialized (empty). If i replace the string with char* its initialized in my expected order.

However on another program the same classes for configuration work, so i dont know the problem.

There is another question but not the same since [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467919/static-const-string-wont-get-initialized) its not a global.

Comment: That's not enough to go by. Provide a minimum compilable example,

Comment: Looks like [Static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/static-init-order.html).

Comment: I cannot , because its in a project and if i do the test in a clean simple project without all the complex , so it will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It gets initialized, of course. However, it is likely being initialized in the order you don't want/expect it initialized in.

Specifically, it is probably not constructed by the time you use it because you use it during construction of another global.

Unfortunately, you don't have a good way to *portably* specify initialization order of global data. Initialization order among multiple files is not defined by the standard, although it is likely specified by your *toolchain*. Consequently, altering the order of compilation or building using another toolchain can result in a different initialization order. Search for "static initialization order fiasco" for more details.

One way to avoid this issue is to declare your static data in a function:

```
const std::string& AppConfigFileName() {
  static const std::string name("cfg");
  return name;
}
```

Although...I don't see why this must be static (the function above allows you to return by value -- no need for static). Plus, I don't see why this could not be a plain C string, since you just treat it as a C string in your config loader.

Comment: It's probably static because he got a linker error when he was trying to use it extern or without either extern or static. static fixed his error, and he kept it...

Comment: You are correct there is no reason that it will be static (bad habits from java const def) . Is there any meaning between const to static const for a global?

Comment: This is exactly the point - "Specifically, it is probably not constructed by the time you use it because you use it during construction of another global." , maybee this cause the difference between machines with the same program.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore i was actually questioning why it must be static not for visibility, but for lifetime.

Comment: @user1495181 `const` means the same for a global.

Comment: @user1495181 well, simply altering order of compiled files is enough to change the initialization order of globals. even running it through another toolchain can produce another initialization order of your globals.

Comment: @justin, i will add the comment about order and toochain to your answer. it explain the reason why its not the same between computers and programs.

Answer (score 2):

The key issue is when `Configuration::loadConfiguration` is called.  The
order of initialization **between** translation units is undefined, so
if `Configuration::loadConfiguration` is called from the constructor of
a static object in another translation unit, the variable may not have
been constructed.  In this particular case, the simplest solution is
just to change the type to `char const[]`; this allows static 
initialization, which occurs before any dynamic initialization.  (Any
initialization which involves non-trivial constructors is dynamic.)
More generally, you could use the singleton pattern for the string.

Several other points are worth mentioning as well:

- You've declared a `static` instance of an object in a header file.
  This means that every translation unit which includes the header file
  will have a separate instance of the object.  This is probably not a
  good idea.
- You output `APP_CONFIG_FILE_NAME.data()`.  This is simply the data in
  the `std::string` object—it is **not** guaranteed to be `'\0'`
  terminated.  When you need a `'\0'` terminated string, you must use
  `std::string::c_str()`.  (But in this case, you can just output the
  `std::string`.  There's no need for any function call on it.)